# A question about React Native Licence and any legal issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We are currently in the planning phases of a new Social Media app. We want to build it in React Native, due to working with javascript, etc.

Now I couldn't get a complete answer when looking online but I want to ask you, if there would be any legal issues if would ever go public and get any success, since we would be a direct competitor with Facebook.

If you have any advice about this I would be were happy to hear it.

Comment: Good to see you're planning ahead

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/LICENSE, This is on facebooks' own account.

Also there are resources like this on the web https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-conditions-of-the-React-Native-license